# How to filter packets via iptables by regular expression?

Tags: regex, linux, iptables

everybody!

I need to filter packets by regular expression using `iptables`, but this command:

```
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m string --string "^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$" --algo regex -p sctp -j DROP
```

Causes this error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

As somebody said to me, it happens because regex algo is too slow for this chain.
I've tried to use it in other chains but got the same error

Is this method even possible? How can I do it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Kindly share the input and expected output

Comment: Are there any specific type of packets you want to filter ?
Please mention the chain and internet packet type.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/smcho-kr/kpcre/

You can find iptables regex extension module [here](https://github.com/smcho-kr/kpcre/).
After you install the module, you won't get the error message.